# Discord.py Member "<@userid>" not found. Error

Tags: discord, discord.py

It's just part of a command

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def rstaff(self,ctx,member:discord.Member,role:discord.Role):
    admin = ctx.author
    chanel= self.bot.get_channel(1080557591899406366)
    lembed = discord.Embed(title="✅Administrator Log", description=f"**
Remove Stuff Command Used**\nAdmin:{admin.mention}\nUser:{member.name}\n
Authorization received:{role.mention}", colour=discord.Colour.green())
    embed = discord.Embed(title="✅Administrator", description=f"{member.mention} 
From {role.mention} authorization received. Admin:{admin.mention}",colour=discord.Colour.green())
    await member.remove_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await chanel.send(embed=lembed)
```

chanel= ctx.self.bot.get_channel(1080557591899406366)

"Error: self is a required argument that is missing."

I change it

chanel= self.bot.get_channel(1080557591899406366)

"Error: Member<@&777487631889072138>" not found."

I added it to the beginning of the substructure

```
@client.event
async def on_ready(self):
    await self.client.wait_until_ready()
    self.server = self.client.get_guild(client.server_id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You command stands alone and is not in a class so there is no `self`. Simply, remove `self` and read up on [commands.Context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?#discord.ext.commands.Context).

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles = True)
async def rstaff(ctx, member: discord.Member, role: discord.Role):
    admin = ctx.author
    chanel = bot.get_channel(1080557591899406366)
    lembed = discord.Embed(...)
    embed = discord.Embed(...)
    await member.remove_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await chanel.send(embed=lembed)
```

Documentation: [commands.Bot](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?#discord.ext.commands.Bot), [get_channel()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_channel)